# What were the words used by Frasier and Niles Crane as a synonym for conundrum?

Tags: dialogue, frasier

In one of the episodes of Frasier (I cannot recall the exact episode number) the brothers are describing a difficult situation, using different words. I believe some of those were in different languages (I can only guess is French?).

The dialogue is fuzzy in my head but it goes something like:

> **Frasier**: I find myself in a sort of [X], well maybe not [X], more of a [Y]. Or maybe more of a [Z].
>   **Niles**: Why, what happened?
>   **Frasier**: [explains]
>   **Niles**: That's not a [Z], that's more of a [A]!

**What were those words and what do they mean?**

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You seem to mean this dialogue from the [season 9 opener](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0582385/combined):

> **Frasier:** Niles, listen, I didn't want to say anything in front of the others, but I find myself in a bit of a *quandary*. Well, it's not so much a quandary, really, it's more of a *pickle*.  Well, not so much a pickle, but well, no more than a... *cornichon*.
>
> **Niles:** What is it?
>
> **Frasier:** I think I want to be with Lana, not Claire.
>
> **Niles:** Forgive me, Frasier, but that's one big-ass cornichon.

Basically, 2 things are happening here:

1. Frasier is trying to **pretend he has a small problem**, but as Niles suggests, it's actually a big one. His phrases are progressively diminutive: 'Quandary' is a difficult dilemma, 'pickle' is [slang](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=pickle) for a small predicament, and 'cornichon' is a [small pickle](http://www.foodrepublic.com/2013/06/05/what-is-a-cornichon/), hence an even smaller problem.
2. Frasier and his brother are often **portrayed as pretentious**. So when they converse, they're prone to use classy words like 'quandary' (instead of 'problem') and French foodie terms like 'cornichon' (The Crane brothers *love* French, gourmet food, and French gourmet food). This tendency is then humoristically undercut when Niles uncharacteristically says 'big-ass'.

Comment: `often portrayed as pretentious` your description is diminutive :P

Comment: To be fair, Frasier was Flanderized in that respect as the show went on (but I think Niles was always like that).

Comment: aaand now I miss this show even more.